# ActiveMQ PooledConnectionFactory without spring

Tags: java, activemq-classic

Can you, please, give me a help on one simple problem. 
I need to use PooledConnectionFactory without spring, JMSTemplate. ActiveMQ says that this class is pooling connections, producers, sessions, and what is confusing me, I don't know how to get them from instance. I was waiting for some takeConnection(), and then realeaseConnection()  and takeProducer() and realize producer(). 
What should I do after pooledConnectionFactory.start(); Normaly, I would do Connection c = pooledConnectionFactory.createConnection... Hope, I explained my problem. And how producers and sessions are pooled, if they are created directly from Connection.

```
    connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(
            userId, 
            passWord, 
            brokerURL);
    log.info("Queueing service init: BrokerURL: " + brokerURL + "  UserId: " + userId + "   Paasword: " + passWord);

    pooledConnectionFactory = new PooledConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);

    pooledConnectionFactory.setIdleTimeout(5000);
    pooledConnectionFactory.setMaxConnections(10);
    pooledConnectionFactory.setMaximumActive(5000);
    pooledConnectionFactory.start();
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, the pooled connection factory is just as any other jms connection factory when it comes to using it.

Just call:

pooledConnectionFactory.createConnection(); // as you would

The connection factory will not really create connections but give you a pooled one. Then, connection.close(); will release it to the pool again. But all that is under the hood, just use it as you are used to and it will be just fine. The same goes for sessions and producers, but not consumers.

Comment: Oh, Thank's, I will try today. I think, I made wrong tests. I created pool with 1 connection, then created 2 connection and compared them, they were not equal, but I didn't called .close()  Hope, this is what I need

Comment: I tried to implement like you said, so I have pooledConnectionFactory, I created connections with createConnection();  on connection instances, I called start and close. It works, but it seems to be slower than using one connection. And in activeMQ console on http://localhost:8161/admin/topics.jsp I can see helper topics with connections which increases very fast (in one connection I had here about 10 topic messages, here I have thousand) so in seems that connections are created every time and not returned to pool, also all my memory is out and computer begins working bad.

Comment: Well, I have not played much with these things to know for sure. One thing though, if you are using a pooled connection factory, the pooling is for producer,session and connection. You should not need to call .start() since that is starting receiving messages if you fire up a listener or consumer. For that, use an ordinary CF.

Comment: Yes, I was looking activemq sources, and I'm now sure that you are right about pooling and working with it. But I still doesn't undertand, why I have so poor perfomance. And I have one more problem when started with pooling: is there any possibility to close sessions and consumers from Connection B, while they were created in connection A?

Comment: And how can I see, that connections are really the same for example create one, stop (it is return to pool), create second. And watch if they are the same?